# Using Binding.IndexerName and Binding.ProvideValue in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement the answer in this so [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554561/re-evaluate-all-values-in-xaml-page-calculated-by-a-markup-extension/40567656#40567656)

The problem is, that in xamarin forms 2 ingredients do not exist (or I have not found them yet):

- Binding.IndexerName
- Binding.ProvideValue()

I do not know why they do not exist. Maybe nobody has implemented them, maybe there is a technical reason why they cannot be implemented.

Can I still get the in xamarin forms?
Maybe in another way?

Answer (score 0):

First, note that this answer probably doesn't work with `Xamarin.Forms`, or at least not with `XamlC` on.

If you want to get that working, your MarkupExtensions have to implement `IMarkupExtension<BindingBase>` instead of `IMarkupExtension`.

`ProvideValue()` is not defined in the `Binding` class, but in `BindingExtension`, but you probably won't win anything by instantiating a `BindingExtension` and calling `ProvideValue` on it versus returning the Binding directly.

The `IndexerName` refers to the `IndexerName` attribute of the `Translator` class. As you're not using it, the default is "Item", and you can use that hardcoded value.

Comment: Why do you assume it does not work with Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Probably because I wrote the Xaml Parser and Compiler for Xamarin.Forms...

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks for helping me by the way! My question was not precise. Which part of you answer does not work with xamarin.forms?