# How can I tell the NotifyPropertyChanged Method which property changed if the property does not seem to have a name?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

Hi I am trying to tell the INotifyPropertyChangedHandler which property changed. Unfortuanatly I think the method only works receiving a string. My code looks like this:

```
 public class Placeholder
    {
        
        public String ResourceId { get; set; }
        
        public Placeholder(String resourceId)
        {
            
            ResourceId = resourceID;

        }
    }
```

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Placeholder> List { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
           List = new ObservableCollection<Placeholder>();
           Reset(); //Fills the List with all kinds of Placeholders with implemented Id's
           InitializeComponent();
        }
       
  
        public string  this [int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return List[index].ResourceId;
            }
        } 
// Now I would like to have a method that looks anyhere like this:

private void NotifyPropertyChanged( int index = 0)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                // It should somehow tell the System which Property changed by an index
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(""));
            }
        }
       
    }
```

My xaml btw looks something like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinRocketsPapa"
             x:Class="XamarinRocketsPapa.MainPage"
             x:Name = "Main"
             Padding="5,20,5,5"
             BindingContext="{x:Reference Main}">
 <local:CustomButton
                Source="{Binding [7] , Converter={StaticResource StringToSourceConverter}}"
                Number="7">
 </local:CustomButton>
</ContentPage>
```

Thank you alot for helping me!

Comment: May I ask why not bind to your `List` property and use its predefined indexer operator?

Answer (score 1):

For changes to your indexer property, use [the `Binding.IndexerName` constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.indexername).

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged( int index = 0)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Binding.IndexerName));
    }
}
```

Looking at [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/Binding.cs,673), this is a constant string with the value `"Item[]"`.

#### Edit:

For Xamarin, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40606943/124386) suggests you should just use the string `"Item"` instead.

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged( int index = 0)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you alot! Where exactly should this constant be placed and how does it work?

Comment: It's already defined; it's part of the WCF `PresentationFramework` library.

Comment: Thats what i thought... If I copy paste your code Binding.IndexerName underlines red... Am I missing something @RichardDeeming ?

Comment: Do you have a `using System.Windows.Data;` line at the top of your file, and a reference to the `PresentationFramework` assembly?

Comment: Does it also work on Xamarin? I'm new to programming with C#... when I write ```using System.Windows.Data``` Data underlines red. And I don't really know what you mean by reference to the assembly. Excuse my lack of knowledge xD I'm just trying to teach myself AppDevelopment by myself... Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Ah, no; that reference was for WPF. For Xamarin, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40606943/124386) seems to suggest you can just use the name `"Item"` instead.

Comment: Alright so I will write ```handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));``` ? @Richard Deeming ?

Comment: I got it !!!! Thanks the answer was:

Comment: ```private void NotifyPropertyChanged( int index = 0)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs($"Item[{index}]"));
            }
        }```

Comment: @LucaHafer you should post the solution as an answer to the question instead of a comment

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that works and solves my problem, based on @Richard Deeming's answer and the discussion that followed:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged( int index = 0)         
{             
   var handler = PropertyChanged;           
   if (handler != null)
   {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs($"Item[{index}]"));             
   }
}
```