# Using an IValueConverter on non bound data in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I have an `IValueConverter` that I wrote to handle localization and translation in WPF elements;

```
public class LanguageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

        if (value is string)
            return LocalizedStrings.Retreive((string)value);
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But I also want to use it in non bound data aswell, ie send a known string into the converter rather than a property from the elements data context. How can I go about that?

Guess I should clarify, my intent is to use this in XAML for the UI and would be helpful if it had a design time support aswell.

I did attempt a variation that used the `ConverterParameter` to feed the source string, but in design time all my text is replaced with System.Object text, so not very useful.

Would also like if at all possible to avoid creating a overloaded or inherited user-control.

Comment: Simple call the function like any other function.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan As far as I know you cannot call functions in XAML.

Comment: @Wobbles You haven't said anything about XAML in your question. Please be more specific. Try to give an example of how you want to use the converter outside of a Binding.

Comment: @Clemens I edited to clarify, but I did say "translation in WPF elements"

Comment: @Clemens Hence the clarification, I wrongly assumed people got that part without the need to say it since the IValConv implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my previous comment. What I actually was trying to say is that "translation in WPF elements" does not necessarily mean XAML. More or less everything you do in XAML can also be done in code behind, where it would be easy to instantiate and use a converter. If you give a XAML example of how you intend to apply such a conversion, it might be possible to answer your question.

Comment: @Clemens well I plan to use it literally everywhere, for example `<TextBlock Text="Announcements" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>` I would like to apply the converter to the `Text` DP.

Comment: @Wobbles Do you want to apply conversion while the user types in ? Or, anything else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a `MarkupExtension` that would take a `string` as a parameter and call your converter in the `ProvideValue` override. Here's an example implementation:

```
public class TranslateExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public TranslateExtension(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }

    private static readonly LanguageConverter _converter = new LanguageConverter();

    public string Text { get; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return _converter.Convert(Text, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Then you'd use it in XAML like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{local:Translate 'text to translate'}" />
```

Note though that changing language will require the XAML to be re-read as the `ProvideValue` method is only called once upon realization of your XAML definition. If you want a dynamic approach you could refer for example to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554561/re-evaluate-all-values-in-xaml-page-calculated-by-a-markup-extension/40567656#40567656) answer.

Comment: Would this work during design time? So far my biggest peeve about a lot of localization solutions is all the text is blank during design.

Comment: Yes, it should work in design time since the extension parameter is a `string` constant. At least it does work for me. But it all depends on whether your `LocalizedStrings.Retreive((string)value)` call will work at design time.

Comment: Than this may be exactly what I was looking to do, will test now.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar ;-) absolutely what i wanted to achieve!

Comment: Did you somehow manage to miss my comment about implementing a custom markup extension?

Answer (score 0):

> But I also want to use it in non bound data aswell, ie send a known string into the converter rather than a property from the elements data context. How can I go about that?

You can't really do this because the Convert method of a Converter will only be invoked when the binding to the source property is resolved and when the source property is updated. If the binding to the source property fails, for example when you have defined an invalid binding path in your XAML markup or when there simply is no DataContext to bind to, your Convert method won't be called.

And when there is no binding applied to the target property at all, the converter won't be invoked either.

So you will have to always make sure that there actually is a property to bind to for this to work. Maybe you can bind to a dummy property or something.

Comment: While I suspect this is the right track, my attempt to do so then pass the original string through the `ConverterParameter` resulted in all my text reading "System Object" at design time. I would like to avoid this. I am not against changing my approach either,

Comment: Maybe you could write your own custom markup extension that performs the localization instead of using a converter: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf/

Comment: What do you think about creating a keyed collection extending the dictionary class that implements my translating then binding directly to that and calling my original string as the key? May not be standard practice but if it works implementation would be as simple as `{Vinding localization:Store[My English phrase to convert]}`. Hopefully this works at design time aswell.

Comment: It sounds reasonable provided that you expose the Dictionary through a property of the DataContext of the control.