# Xamarin.Forms change UI language at runtime (XAML)

Tags: xaml, localization, xamarin.forms

I am using `Strings.resx`, `Strings.de.resx`, etc. to localize `Xamarin.Forms` app.
I need to be able to change interface language at run time, and it (allmost) works.

Xamarin generates `static class Strings` in `namespace MyProject.Resources` from resource files, and I use those values to display strings on UI.
When doing it from code, it works flawlessly:

```
await DisplayAlert(Strings.lblConfirmDelete, Strings.lblDeleteMessage, Strings.lblOK, Strings.lblCancel));
```

Problem is - not all attributes defined this way from XAML are updated when I change UI culture during runtime.
Buttons, Labels, Entry properties (Placeholder etc.) change as they should, but PageTitle, Toolbaritems, and some other properties remain in previous language.

I presume that some of these are populated when Page is first created, and are not updated on culture (and UI culture) change. 
So, basically, I need a way to combine `{DynamicResource ...}` with values from resources.
I know that `DynamicResource` is ment to be used with Resource dictionary, but that is not a good way to store language translations for localization.

I tried

```
Text="{DynamicResource {x:Static lr:Strings.lblAddNew}}"
```

also not working.

Is there a way of refreshing page dynamicaly?

I also tried calling

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(MainListPage));
```

from Appearing event for that page, but that also does not work.

Any ideas?

### Part of XAML file

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.View"
    xmlns:rs="clr-namespace:MMPI"
    x:Class="MyProject.MainListPage"
    xmlns:lr="clr-namespace:MyProject.Resources"

    Title="{x:Static lr:Strings.appName}"
    >

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem 
     Name="New" 
     Order="Primary" 
     Priority="0"
     Text="{x:Static lr:Strings.lblAddNew}" 
     Clicked="New_Clicked"
>
```

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-evaluate all values in xaml page calculated by a markup-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554561/re-evaluate-all-values-in-xaml-page-calculated-by-a-markup-extension)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When i encountered that challenge in a project I resolved it by using a simple class `ResourceLoader` and making use of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

You can access the `Instance`property from anywhere and change the culture. All String that are bound to the index would update.

The `ResourceManager` instance injected into the constructor must be set up appropriately.

```cs
public class ResourceLoader : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ResourceManager manager;
    private CultureInfo cultureInfo;

    public ResourceLoader(ResourceManager resourceManager)
    {
        this.manager = resourceManager;
        Instance = this;
        this.cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    }

    public static ResourceLoader Instance { get; private set; }

    public string GetString(string resourceName)
    {
        string stringRes = this.manager.GetString(resourceName, this.cultureInfo);
        return stringRes;
    }

    public string this[string key] => this.GetString(key);

    public void SetCultureInfo(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        this.cultureInfo = cultureInfo;
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

---

To display the localized strings in your application you need to bind through the indexer like so:

```
<Label Text="{Binding [Test], Source={x:Static ResourceLoader.Instance}}" />
```

Since it is now bound it should update when you call `ResourceLoader.SetCultureInfo` because the `Item[]` 'PropertyName' is causing bound controls to re-fetch the values to their bound keys.

---

### Update

I just tested it if i was talking bogus and for some reason the property changed didn't work. I've added a different approach below, which is close to what i'm using in production **i urge you to add some kind of weak reference 'caching' instead of the simple list holding all the string resources** (otherwise they will be kept forever)

I'm keeping above for reference.

```cs
public class ResourceLoader
{

    public ResourceLoader(ResourceManager resourceManager)
    {
        this.manager = resourceManager;
        Instance = this;
        this.cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    }

    private readonly ResourceManager manager;
    private CultureInfo cultureInfo;

    private readonly List<StringResource> resources = new List<StringResource>();

    public static ResourceLoader Instance { get; private set; }

    public StringResource this[string key] {
        get { return this.GetString(key); }
    }

    public StringResource GetString(string resourceName)
    {
        string stringRes = this.manager.GetString(resourceName, this.cultureInfo);
        var stringResource = new StringResource(resourceName, stringRes);
        this.resources.Add(stringResource);
        return stringResource;
    }

    public void SetCultureInfo(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        this.cultureInfo = cultureInfo;
        foreach (StringResource stringResource in this.resources) {
            stringResource.Value = this.manager.GetString(stringResource.Key, cultureInfo);
        }
    }

}
```

StringResource:

```cs
public class StringResource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public StringResource(string key, string value)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    private string value;

    public string Key { get; }

    public string Value {
        get { return this.value; }
        set {
            this.value = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

XAML Binding

```
<Label  Text="{Binding [ResourceKey].Value, Mode=OneWay, Source={x:Static local:ResourceLoader.Instance}}" 
           />
```

---

### Update 2

Came across [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/82458/binding-indexername-and-binding-providevalue-in-xamarin-forms) where they implemented it similarly to my first approach. Maybe you can give it a try.

---

### Update 3

Fixed the first approach. Both are working now. What was needed was `this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));` instead of `this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Item[]));`

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I'm sorry, but I don't quite follow. If I create an instance of ResourceLoader class using the ResourceManager from auto-generated file (Strings.Designer.cs), what am I supposed to do next? Could you please give me an example usage in a couple of lines? Nothing too elaborate, just 1-2-3 steps.

Comment: i've checked what i proposed and updated my answer with a different - properly working approach

Answer (score 0):

I solved it very similar to @woelliJ . I just wanted to have key as strongly types from static class and binding should be in code behind.

ITranslationService is singleton from static variable. It is very close like @woelliJ .

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public sealed class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension<BindingBase>
{
    private readonly ITranslationService? _translationService;

    public TranslateExtension()
    {
        _translationService = Mobile.App.TranslationService;
    }

    public string? Text { get; set; }

    public BindingBase ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var translationItem = _translationService[Text];

        var binding = new Binding
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = $"Value",
            Source = translationItem,
        };

        return binding;
    }

    object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return (this as IMarkupExtension<BindingBase>).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}

[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class TranslationItem
{
    public string? Key { get; set; }
    public string? Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then label would be like this

```
<Label FontSize="Title" Text="{services:Translate Text={x:Static models:M.AboutTestInfoTitle}}" />
```