# Xamarin Cross Platform: default views language

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a multi-language application, where the user selects their language using a picker and the text of the components (lables, buttons...) is filled through resources. The problem is that the views, such as the DatePicker, Calendar ... continue to show the names of the days, months, accept and cancel buttons ... in English. Is there any way to modify it?

Comment: these values are set depending on the system level locale settings

Comment: This discussion may be helpful for you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410407/xamarin-forms-change-ui-language-at-runtime-xaml