# WPF - How to pass string to xaml from c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on localization with 'ini' files.
But I don't know how to pass strings to XAML from c#

I did it with c# like this:

```
using System. Windows;
using IniHandler;

namespace BMSound
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AboutWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AboutWindow : Window
    {
        public AboutWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SaveINI ini = new SaveINI(SettingLoc.settingsFilePath());
            productName.Text = ini.Read("General", "ProductName");
            productVersion.Text = ini.Read("General", "Version");

            Lang lang = new Lang();
            this.Title = lang.Get("Titles", "About");
        }
    }
}
```

But I think it's not the best way. And I don't know how to do in XAML

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">
    <!--Product Name Here-->
</TextBlock>
```

I'm new to XAML. It was easy with WinForms :(

Comment: I'll agree with it not being the best way, but it is the only way, except if you want to re-engineer and re-write the entire WPF project to be [MVVM](https://intellitect.com/getting-started-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-pattern-using-windows-presentation-framework-wpf/)

Comment: check out databinding in wpf and have a look into this [how-to-create-a-simple-binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-a-simple-binding)

Answer (score 0):

To do this fully inside XAML you would need to move more to an MVVM approach. You can write [markup extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.markupextension?view=netcore-3.1) for xaml and use them to provide data binded to f.e. some "translation manager".

Every time the language changes you would need to signal the binding used in your markup extension to update itself.

This enables you to do something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{l:Translator SomeMeaningfullID}"/>
```

in your Xaml and by magic of MarkupExtension the translation for the given ID would be substituted.

If you google for `C# markup extensions translation site:stackoverflow.com` you find plenty of posts you can read for more in depth information:

- [How do I resolve the value of a databinding inside a MarkupExtension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985902/how-do-i-resolve-the-value-of-a-databinding-inside-a-markupextension/48090008#48090008)
- [Re-evaluate all values in xaml page calculated by a markup-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554561/re-evaluate-all-values-in-xaml-page-calculated-by-a-markup-extension/40567656)
- [Change language runtime with wrapped language resources Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636734/change-language-runtime-with-wrapped-language-resources-xamarin-forms)
- ... etc ...

There are also ressources by Microsoft:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/creating
- https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml

or others that even touch upon using MarkupExtensions for translation purposes:

- https://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html

Some of the links are offsite - if they go stale in the future this won't help much. The onsite-links could help you out though.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with an indexer property in your ViewModel. Create a property with an index, and in the XAML you can access this property like an array.

```
public class InfoViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ResourceStringProvider _language;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a bindable indexed property to load localized text resources.
    /// In Xaml one can use it like this:
    /// <code>
    /// Text="{Binding Language[MyTextResource]}"
    /// </code>
    /// </summary>
    public ResourceStringProvider Language
    {
        get { return _language ?? (_language = new ResourceStringProvider()); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class which provides an indexer property to the language resources.
    /// </summary>
    public class ResourceStringProvider
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a given localized text resource.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Name of the text resource.</param>
        /// <returns>Localized text resource.</returns>
        public string this[string id]
        {
            get
            {
                // return the localized text for the given id
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To access the language resource in the view:

```
<Button ToolTip="{Binding Language[back]}"></Button>
```