# xamarin forms localization with assemblyInfo class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to implement localization into my xamarin forms project.

I use latest version of xf.

I implemented my localization accordingly from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows)
It works when I changed language on my phone, it shows other language which is ok.

PROBLEM:
How to add for example two buttons on my SettingsPage and to be able to switch between languages?

I added in my AssemblyInfo class only
`[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]`

And for example my Settings Page have two buttons (two languages - english and serbian)

```
<StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Please choose language"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="EN" Command="{Binding SwitchLanguageCommand}" CommandParameter="en-US"/>
                <Button Text="RS" Command="{Binding SwitchLanguageCommand}" CommandParameter="sr-Latn-RS"/>
            </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

How can I change languages in the runtime?
In my ViewModel I just added the method which is refering to SwitchLanguageCommand:

```
 public class SettingsViewModel
    {
        public SettingsViewModel()
        {
            SwitchLanguageCommand = new Command(async (culture) => await ChangeLanguage(culture));
        }

        private async Task ChangeLanguage(object culture)
        {
            CultureInfo myCulture = new CultureInfo(culture as String);
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = myCulture; 
        }

        public ICommand SwitchLanguageCommand { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You need to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`  in the ViewModel . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410407/xamarin-forms-change-ui-language-at-runtime-xaml

Comment: hmm, it works on regular page, but if I want to change kanguage dynamically on Shell.xaml it doesnt works, Binding is empty, and I see empty items in my hamburger menu

Comment: You could share your sample so that I can test it on my side directly .