# Xamarin.forms Change Language at runtime

Tags: xamarin.forms, localization

I have a login page and my code is this:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="20">
                <Entry Placeholder="{x:Static resources:AppResources.EMB_PLACEHOLDER}" Keyboard="Numeric"  Text="{Binding EMB}"></Entry>
                <Button Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.LOGIN_BTN}" TextColor="White" Padding="0,-20" BackgroundColor="#07987f" Command="{Binding LoadLoginCommand}"></Button>
                <Label
                 Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.MESSAGE} "></Span>
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>
                <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Padding="20,0,0,0" Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.LBLLANGUAGE}" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Body" TextColor="Gray" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Picker x:Name="languagePicker" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}" Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.LBLLANGUAGE}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}"></Picker>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></ActivityIndicator>
                <Label Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.TSMSG1}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Have a picker with list of languages. Also have `resx` file for every language. My scenario is when i click on picker and select some language i want to change the language of all text on the login page in choosed language in realtime. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You can check : https://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2017/05/20/dynamically-binding-resx-resources-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: You could use `ResourceManager` . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410407/xamarin-forms-change-ui-language-at-runtime-xaml

Answer (score 0):

The first link provided in the comments is an awesome solution, however for the shake of simplicity, a very simple way of doing what you want is to bind the control's text to properties in the ViewModel:

`<Label Text="{Binding TSMSG1}"...`

rather than using

`<Label Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.TSMSG1}"...`

Then in your ViewModel you would have a property `TSMSG1` (and others) that you manually update when the language changes. Of course those properties need to follow INPC pattern for the changes to be reflected on the view.

I would not recommend doing this everywhere because bindings are expensive for your app performance, but it should be fine for the screen that changes the language.