# How Change the CultureInfo Dynamically in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i need to creata a app with support multilingual.

So i did a sample app like below.

**Page.xamal**

```
<StackLayout
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{x:Static local:AppResources.Title}" TextColor="Black"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <Button Text="{x:Static local:AppResources.ClickMe}" Clicked="Button1_Clicked"/>

            <Label Text="{x:Static local:AppResources.Title}" TextColor="Black"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <Button Text="{x:Static local:AppResources.ClickMe}" Clicked="Button2_Clicked"/>
            
        </StackLayout>
```

**page.xamal.cs**

```
private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("th");
            AppResources.Culture = culture;
        }
```

as xmarin forms documentation provide i set the AssemblyInfo.cs (Common folder)

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-GB")]
```

so my default language is "en-GB".

i have 3 AppRerources.resx

1. AppResources.resx
2. AppResources.th.resx
3. AppResources.en-GB.resx

but when i press first button i could not see that app is changing the language.

anything i missed here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin.Forms change UI language at runtime (XAML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410407/xamarin-forms-change-ui-language-at-runtime-xaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About changing current cultureinfo, I suggest you can try to use **Plugin.Multilingual** to get it.

[image]

firstly, installing Plugin.Multilingual by nuget package, define .resx file like this:

[image]

In TranslateExtension.cs file in the constant ResourceId by default it will assume your resource file is added in the root of the project and the resx file is named as AppResources. If you added it to a folder or named the resx file differently you can change it there.

```
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    const string ResourceId = "MultilingualSample.AppResources";

    static readonly Lazy<ResourceManager> resmgr = new Lazy<ResourceManager>(() => new ResourceManager(ResourceId, typeof(TranslateExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly));

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Text == null)
            return "";

        var ci = CrossMultilingual.Current.CurrentCultureInfo;

        var translation = resmgr.Value.GetString(Text, ci);

        if (translation == null)
        {

     #if DEBUG
            throw new ArgumentException(
                String.Format("Key '{0}' was not found in resources '{1}' for culture '{2}'.", Text, ResourceId, ci.Name),
                "Text");
  #else
            translation = Text; // returns the key, which GETS DISPLAYED TO THE USER
  #endif
        }
        return translation;
    }
}
```

More detailed info, please take a look:

https://github.com/CrossGeeks/MultilingualPlugin

Comment: I am currently using this, this is working in debug mode
but not in the release mode.

can you provide me your sample

Answer (score 1):

Pass argument in CultureInfo the culture you want to set , e.g. I set it to *German* in my example

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```