# Refresh UI after new Language Xamarin

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.forms, refresh, translation

[Re-evaluate all values in xaml page calculated by a markup-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554561/re-evaluate-all-values-in-xaml-page-calculated-by-a-markup-extension/56131214#56131214)

I try to implement this solution, but I Have a ObservableCollection which contains Title to binding in my listview in my MasterDetails page and it doesn't work. I have really no idea how implement this, but for only one label I did it successful. If someone can help me. Thanks

My list of items :

```
public ObservableCollection<MainMenuViewItem> MenuItems {
            get {
                return new ObservableCollection<MainMenuViewItem>(new[]
                {
                    new MainMenuViewItem { Id = 0, Title = Translator.TranslatorInstance["lblHome"], TargetType=typeof(HybridWebView),ViewModelType=HybridViewTypeEnum.Home },
                    new MainMenuViewItem { Id = 1, Title = Translator.TranslatorInstance["lblListOfDeliverySlip"], TargetType=typeof(HybridWebView),ViewModelType=HybridViewTypeEnum.ListDeliverySlip },
                    new MainMenuViewItem { Id = 2, Title = Translator.TranslatorInstance["lblSettings"], TargetType=typeof(ParametersView)}
                });
            }
        }
```

My view

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MenuListPage" SeparatorVisibility="None" 
              HasUnevenRows="true" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="15,10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='{0}',Source={x:Static translate:Translator.TranslatorInstance}}" 
                                FontSize="24"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

The translationExtension class

```
/// <summary>
        /// Current culture info
        /// </summary>
        public static CultureInfo CultureInfoApp { get; private set; }

        // Path of folder where is store each file language + Name of file without .en ( language code ) 
        private const string ResourceId = "Landauer.Mobile.Ressources.Language.LanguageRessource"; 

        // Instanciation differed of Ressourcemanager
        public static readonly Lazy<ResourceManager> RessourceManagerLanguage = new Lazy<ResourceManager>(() => new ResourceManager(ResourceId, IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(TranslateExtension)).Assembly));

        /// <summary>
        /// Match to the name of the label into .resx file
        /// </summary>
        public string Text { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        public TranslateExtension()
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS || Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                // Get dependency in each specific platform
                CultureInfoApp = DependencyService.Get<ILanguage>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();
            }
            //Text = text;
        }

        object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }

        public BindingBase ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var binding = new Binding
            {
                Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                Path = $"[{Text}]",
                Source = Translator.TranslatorInstance,
            };
            return binding;
        }
```

And finally my translator class:

```
public static Translator TranslatorInstance => _uniqueInstance;

        /// <summary>
        /// When TranslateExtension you create new Binding(), call this "Callback"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string this[string text]
        {
            get
            {
                return TranslateExtension.RessourceManagerLanguage.Value.GetString(text, TranslateExtension.CultureInfoApp);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implementation of notifications
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// At each time you set language use this method to refresh UI
        /// </summary>
        public void Invalidate()
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
        }
```

Comment: there is no way we can help you if you don't bother to show us what you are doing.  A vague description of the problem is useless without any code illustrating what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @Jason Ok sorry I forget, I have modify.

Comment: does your translator class implement INotifyPropertyChanged?  Are you calling Invlaidate() when the language changes?

Comment: Why do you call Translator.TranslatorInstance in your XAML if you already call it when instantiating the MenuItems list? For what I understood of your code, you are calling it twice, and the first one already do the translation. If that's the case, why don't you just recreates the list with a RaisePropertyChanged/InvalidProperty?

Comment: @Jason Yes yes I do this. and yes Translator implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @DanielCunha Yes you have right I call twice because I try to test, but futile attempt, I can replace in my list of items by LanguageRessource.nameProperty but it's not working. And what did you say, with recreate a listview with RaisePropertyChanged()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin.Forms change UI language at runtime (XAML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410407/xamarin-forms-change-ui-language-at-runtime-xaml)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the culture of the resource when you change the language.

Your language instance class should also invoke the property change handler when you set the culture.

so create a method in the instance class like below and call when you change the language settings..

```
public void SetCultureInfo(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
    }
```

At the time of language change, the code should be like below

```
var ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar");
                NativeLangUtil.SetLocale(ci); // updating Native 
                Resx.Lang.Strings.Culture = ci; //For .net Resources to work
                Application.Current.Properties["Lang"] = ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;// 
                LangResourceLoader.Instance.SetCultureInfo(ci); //for our use
```

You can find the [sample implementation here](https://xamarinindia.blogspot.com/2018/11/xamarin-forms-rtl-right-to-left-support.html)